# Spotlight not working

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I'm trying to get a spotlight working but it's not showing up could someone have a look and see where I've went wrong?

```
package water3;


import Common.TextureReader;
import com.sun.opengl.util.BufferUtil;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.media.opengl.glu.GLUquadric;
import javax.media.opengl.GL;
import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import javax.media.opengl.glu.GLU;

class Renderer implements GLEventListener {

     private GLUquadric quadric;
     private Object3D object3D;

    private float[] LightPos = {0.0f, 5.0f, -4.0f, 1.0f};   // Light Position
    private boolean LightUp, LightDown, LightLeft, LightRight, LightForward, LightBackward;



    private int[] textures = new int[3];            // Storage For 3 Textures



    double aNum = 1;

    private boolean aDown =false;
    private boolean up =false;


   private GLU glu = new GLU();


    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL gl = drawable.getGL();


        try {

            loadGLTextures(drawable);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't load model/Texture");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

      /*
        gl.glShadeModel(GL.GL_SMOOTH);                              // Enable Smooth Shading
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);                    // Black Background
        gl.glClearDepth(1.0f);                                      // Depth Buffer Setup
        gl.glClearStencil(0);                                       // Stencil Buffer Setup
        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);                              // Enables Depth Testing
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL.GL_LEQUAL);                               // The Type Of Depth Testing To Do
        gl.glHint(GL.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL.GL_NICEST);  // Really Nice Perspective Calculations

      /*  gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT1, GL.GL_POSITION, LightPos, 0);        // Set Light1 Position
        gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT1, GL.GL_AMBIENT, LightAmb, 0);        // Set Light1 Ambience
        gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT1, GL.GL_DIFFUSE, LightDif, 0);        // Set Light1 Diffuse
        gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT1, GL.GL_SPECULAR, LightSpc, 0);        // Set Light1 Specular
        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_LIGHT1);
        */// Enable Light1
                                   // Enable Lighting
/*
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_AMBIENT, MatAmb, 0);         // Set Material Ambience
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_DIFFUSE, MatDif, 0);         // Set Material Diffuse
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_SPECULAR, MatSpc, 0);        // Set Material Specular
        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_SHININESS, MatShn, 0);       // Set Material Shininess
*/
        gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_LIGHT0);
        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glShadeModel(GL.GL_SMOOTH);
        gl.glLightModeli(GL.GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL.GL_TRUE);

        gl.glCullFace(GL.GL_BACK);                                  // Set Culling Face To Back Face
        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_CULL_FACE);                               // Enable Culling
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);                    // Set Clear Color (Greenish Color)

        quadric = glu.gluNewQuadric();                              // Initialize Quadratic
        glu.gluQuadricNormals(quadric, GL.GL_SMOOTH);                      // Enable Smooth Normal Generation
        glu.gluQuadricTexture(quadric, false);





    }




    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {

        GL gl = drawable.getGL();


// Clear Color Buffer, Depth Buffer, Stencil Buffer
        gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        SetSpotlight(gl);
        SetFloorMaterial(gl);


        gl.glPushMatrix();
                                      // Reset Modelview Matrix
                 gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -20.0f);                // Zoom Into The Screen 20 Units

                gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);                                // Enable Texture Mapping ( NEW )
                drawRoom(gl);                                       // Draw The Room


        gl.glPopMatrix();



        gl.glFlush();                                       // Flush The OpenGL Pipeline



    }

    private void drawRoom(GL gl) {                        // Draw The Room (Box)


        gl.glBegin(GL.GL_QUADS);                // Begin Drawing Quads


           // Floor
        gl.glNormal3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);      // Normal Pointing Up
        gl.glVertex3f(-20.0f, -20.0f, -40.0f);  // Back Left
        gl.glVertex3f(-20.0f, -20.0f, 40.0f);  // Front Left
        gl.glVertex3f(20.0f, -20.0f, 40.0f);  // Front Right
        gl.glVertex3f(20.0f, -20.0f, -40.0f);  // Back Right

        // Ceiling

        gl.glNormal3f(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);      // Normal Point Down
        gl.glVertex3f(-10.0f, 10.0f, 20.0f);  // Front Left
        gl.glVertex3f(-10.0f, 10.0f, -20.0f);  // Back Left
        gl.glVertex3f(10.0f, 10.0f, -20.0f);  // Back Right
        gl.glVertex3f(10.0f, 10.0f, 20.0f);  // Front Right


        // Back Wall

        gl.glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);      // Normal Pointing Towards Viewer
        gl.glVertex3f(20.0f, 20.0f, 30.0f);  // Top Right
        gl.glVertex3f(20.0f, -20.0f, 30.0f);  // Bottom Right
        gl.glVertex3f(-20.0f, -20.0f, 30.0f);  // Bottom Left
        gl.glVertex3f(-20.0f, 20.0f, 30.0f);  // Top Left
        // Left Wall
        gl.glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);      // Normal Pointing Right
        gl.glVertex3f(-20.0f, 20.0f, 30.0f);  // Top Front
        gl.glVertex3f(-20.0f, -20.0f, 30.0f);  // Bottom Front
        gl.glVertex3f(-20.0f, -20.0f, -30.0f);  // Bottom Back
        gl.glVertex3f(-20.0f, 20.0f, -30.0f);  // Top Back

        // Right Wall

        gl.glNormal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);     // Normal Pointing Left
        gl.glVertex3f(20.0f, 20.0f, -30.0f);  // Top Back
        gl.glVertex3f(20.0f, -20.0f, -30.0f);  // Bottom Back
        gl.glVertex3f(20.0f, -20.0f, 30.0f);  // Bottom Front
        gl.glVertex3f(20.0f, 20.0f, 30.0f);  // Top Front

         gl.glPushMatrix();
        // Front Wall

                    gl.glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);      // Normal Pointing Away From Viewer
                     gl.glTexCoord2f(1,1);
                    gl.glVertex3f(-20.0f, 20.0f, -30.0f);  // Top Left
                     gl.glTexCoord2f(1,0);
                    gl.glVertex3f(-20.0f, -20.0f, -30.0f);  // Bottom Left
                     gl.glTexCoord2f(0,0);
                    gl.glVertex3f(20.0f, -20.0f, -30.0f);  // Bottom Right
                     gl.glTexCoord2f(0,1);
                    gl.glVertex3f(20.0f, 20.0f, -30.0f);  // Top Right

        gl.glPopMatrix();

        gl.glEnd();                             // Done Drawing Quads


    }



    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable,int xstart,int ystart,int width,int height) {
           GL gl = drawable.getGL();

        height = (height == 0) ? 1 : height;

        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);

        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glRotatef(90, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glu.gluPerspective(60, (float) width / height, 1, 1000);

        glu.gluLookAt(1.0f,0.0f,25.0f,
                      0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,
                      0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();


    }

    public void displayChanged(GLAutoDrawable drawable, boolean modeChanged,boolean deviceChanged) { }


    private void loadGLTextures(GLAutoDrawable gldrawable) throws IOException {
        TextureReader.Texture texture = null;
        texture = TextureReader.readTexture("data/images/04.bmp");

        GL gl = gldrawable.getGL();

        //Create Nearest Filtered Texture
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);

        gl.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                0,
                3,
                texture.getWidth(),
                texture.getHeight(),
                0,
                GL.GL_RGB,
                GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                texture.getPixels());
    }

    public void SetSpotlight(GL gl){

         gl.glDisable(GL.GL_LIGHTING);
                    // prepare spotlight
                    float spot_ambient[] =   {50.2f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f };//white ={10.2f,10.2f,10.2f,1.0f };
                    float spot_diffuse[] =   {50.8f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f };
                    float spot_specular[] =  {50.8f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f };
                    // set colors here and do the geometry in draw
                    gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_AMBIENT,  spot_ambient,0);
                    gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_DIFFUSE,  spot_diffuse,0);
                    gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_SPECULAR, spot_specular,0);
                    gl.glEnable(GL.GL_LIGHTING);
                    gl.glEnable(GL.GL_LIGHT0);
                    // set light position
                    // since ligth follows the model when mousing
                    // spotlight as it moves with the scene

                    float spot_position[] =  {0.0f,60.0f,-30.0f,1.0f};
                    float spot_direction[] = {0.0f,0.0f,-1.0f};
                    float spot_angle = 10.0f;
                    gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_POSITION,  spot_position,0);
                    gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_SPOT_DIRECTION,spot_direction,0);
                    gl.glLightf(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_SPOT_CUTOFF,(float)spot_angle);
                    // "smoothing" the border of the lightcone
                    // change this for effect
                    gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, new float[] {0.7f,0.7f,1}, 0 );
                    gl.glLighti(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, 20);
                gl.glEnable(GL.GL_LIGHTING);
    }

    public void SetFloorMaterial(GL gl){
      float amb[]={0.3f,0.3f,0.0f,1.0f};
      float diff[]={1.0f,1.0f,0.5f,1.0f};
      float spec[]={0.6f,0.6f,0.5f,1.0f};
      float shine=0.25f;
      gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT,GL.GL_AMBIENT,amb,0);
      gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT,GL.GL_DIFFUSE,diff,0);
      gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT,GL.GL_SPECULAR,spec,0);
      gl.glMaterialf(GL.GL_FRONT,GL.GL_SHININESS,shine*128.0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your geometry is getting somewhat illuminated? Be more specific on the result you are getting.

Comment: 1. TLDR 2. Please format code properly.

Comment: Always specify the target OpenGL version when asking about OpenGL.

Comment: we don't edit the question name with `[SOLVED]` here. If you've got your answer, please mark it with the green tick to the left of it - your question will only then be marked as "solved".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL's fixed function pipeline does illumination only at vertices and then just interpolates. Since the walls of your rooms are just very large quads, every wall has only 4 vertices, so only 4 lighting calculations happen. For a spotlight effect you'd need a lot more lighting calculations. So you've to refine (i.e. tesselate) the walls' meshes, or use per pixel lighting (i.e. do lighting calculations on the fragment level – this is done using shaders).